# DJango Querysets Filter

Tags: django

```
    clients = Client.objects.filter(user_id=request.user)
    quotes = Quote.objects.filter(customer_act_id=clients)
```

I have the above code and I am trying to display the users clients and quotes to the user. The clients display fine but the quotes only show the quotes for the FIRST client and not all of them. Any help is appreciated.

Relationships:

User has_many clients(user_id FK) has_many quotes(client_id FK)

Comment: Are you trying to get all quotes for all customers or all quotes for one customer?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying. I am trying to get all the clients that belong to the user and all of the quotes that belong to the clients that belong to the user.

Comment: K, I'm not a Django expert so there are probably better ways to do this but, could you take the client IDs out of clients, put them into a list and then change your customer_act_id = to customer_act_id__in = [your list]?  (FYI, I've spent a few months trying to learn Django and I find it frustrating at times. Sometimes, therefore, I just figure out ways to get the job done rather than BEST ways to get the job done)

Comment: Ben, I actually tried that earlier. It still yields the same result only showing the quotes for client_id 1

Comment: OK. I know this is a stupid question but, are you sure there are multiple quotes in the DB for the client or client's your trying?

Comment: I just added 3 for each client and only the 3 for client_id 1 is showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben is right. Using **customer_act_id__in=clients** should do the trick. Could you double check if the clients are associated with the same user, then?

Comment: I tried this but I did not use the two underscores only one. Can you explain what the __in does?

Comment: Just an FYI it worked like a charm just asking for clarification on what the __ does.

Comment: Oh, the niceties that come after the double underscores are field lookups. A good friend of filters. See more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups